# Pivot table in SharePoint Excel Worbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office365

I am trying to create a PivotTable in a workbook which is located on a SharePoint with data from another workbook located on the same SharePoint site.

I changed the pivot source to: `https://server.sharepoint.com/sites/<censoredsitename>/<alsocensored>/Dashboard/[Apps Dashboard_2018 - Pivot.xlsx]Apps - Daily Data!B1:J22457` in the desktop mode

It refreshes when open it in the desktop mode, but when I try to refresh the pivot table in the web version it throws an error that it cannot find the file: `\sites\<censoredsitename>\<alsocensored>\Dashboard\[Apps Dashboard_2018 - Pivot.xlsx]Apps - Daily Data!B1:J22457`

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT:
Tried changing to: `\\server.sharepoint.com\<censoredsitename>\<alsocensored>\Dashboard\[Apps Dashboard_2018 - Pivot.xlsx]Apps - Daily Data!B1:J22457`, but this does not work on the desktop version. Tried with @SSL as well.